# Simplifying expressions with `Sign` functions to a single piecewise format

Tags: performance-tuning, piecewise

I have the following expression with many `Sign` functions:

```
phase = 2 Sign[t] (1/2 (-1 + e) - 1/2 (1 + e) Sign[t]) + (1/2 (-1 + e1) + 
    1/2 (1 + e1) Sign[d - t1]) (-1 + Sign[t1]) - (1/2 (-e + e1) + 
    1/2 (e + e1) Sign[d + t - t1]) (-1 + 
    Sign[-t + t1]) - (1/2 (-1 + e2) + 1/2 (1 + e2) Sign[d - t2]) (-1 +
     Sign[t2]) + (1/2 (-e + e2) + 1/2 (e + e2) Sign[d + t - t2]) (-1 +
     Sign[-t + t2]) + 
 2 (1/2 (-e1 + e2) + 1/2 (e1 + e2) Sign[t1 - t2]) Sign[-t1 + t2]
```

All variables are assumed to be real. There are 10 different arguments inside `Sign`, namely,

```
t, d-t1, t1, d+t-t1, -t+t1, d-t2, t2, d+t-t2, -t+t2, t1-t2
```

I can assume that all of the above values are nonzero, hence `Sign` function always returns 1 or -1. Then, the above expression `exp` can be written in piecewise format with $2^{10} = 1024$ cases. **How can I convert into this form?**

I tried as follows. First, borrowing the result from [Converting HeavisideTheta[]s and Sign[]s functions to a single Piecewise[]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/47843/converting-heavisidethetas-and-signs-functions-to-a-single-piecewise), define a function

```
ToPiecewise[f_] := 
 PiecewiseExpand[
  f /. {Sign[x_] :> 
     Piecewise[{{1, x > 0}, {-1, x < 0}, {Indeterminate, x == 0}}]}]
```

Since I am only interested when the argument of `Sign` is nonzero, I put `Indeterminate` for `x==0`. This `ToPiecewise` function converts single `Sign` in piecewise format.

By doing

```
Sum[Simplify[PiecewiseExpand[ToPiecewise[phase[[i]]]]], {i, 1, 6}]
```

I obtain the following:

[image]

The result correct, but there are some problems.

1. Anyway, I should some over these terms and collapse into a single piecewise function. However,

   ```
   % // PiecewiseExpand
   ```

takes huge amount of time, hence making me gave up.

2. Some results in the picture are redundant. For example, why one needs the case marked in red? I think removing these redundancy is the key to boost up the performance, but don't know how to do that.

Comment: Re the circled-red `True`: The conditions in the pieces are not exhaustive if `x` is complex.  Try `PiecewiseExpand[expr, assumptions, Reals]` (use `assumptions = True` if no assumptions).

Comment: The following does some meaty simplifications but produces a single (if large) Piecewise expression within half a minute. `ToPiecewise[expr_] := expr /. Sign[x_] -> Which[x > 0, 1, x < 0, -1, True, Indeterminate];` and then `PiecewiseExpand[phase // ToPiecewise, True, Reals, Method -> {"ConditionSimplifier" -> Reduce}]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 Sadly, using `PiecewiseExpand[ToPiecewise[phase[[6]]], True, Reals]` gives the same redundant result.

Comment: @RonaldMonson Thank you so much. It works! I think your comment should be an answer. By the way, is there any difference between `Which` and `Piecewise` inside the definition of `ToPiecewise`? I think changing this gave me a lot of performance boost.

Comment: Try `PiecewiseExpand` with `Method -> {"OrderlessConditions" -> True}`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 That works!

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128637/extraneous-cases-in-simplified-piecewise-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First set up the contingencies

```
phase = 2 Sign[
     t] (1/2 (-1 + e) - 1/2 (1 + e) Sign[t]) + (1/2 (-1 + e1) + 
      1/2 (1 + e1) Sign[d - t1]) (-1 + Sign[t1]) - (1/2 (-e + e1) + 
      1/2 (e + e1) Sign[d + t - t1]) (-1 + 
      Sign[-t + t1]) - (1/2 (-1 + e2) + 
      1/2 (1 + e2) Sign[d - t2]) (-1 + Sign[t2]) + (1/2 (-e + e2) + 
      1/2 (e + e2) Sign[d + t - t2]) (-1 + Sign[-t + t2]) + 
   2 (1/2 (-e1 + e2) + 1/2 (e1 + e2) Sign[t1 - t2]) Sign[-t1 + t2];

ToPiecewise[expr_] := expr /. Sign[x_] :> 
    Piecewise[{{1, x > 0}, {-1, x < 0}, {Indeterminate, x == 0}}];

ToIf[expr_] := expr /. Sign[x_] :> If[x > 0, 1, -1];

ToWhich[expr_] := expr /. Sign[x_] :> 
    Which[x > 0, 1, x < 0, -1, True, Indeterminate];

ToSwitch[expr_] := expr /. Sign[x_] :> Switch[x, y_ /; y > 0, 1, _, -1];
```

With these in place it all depends on what you want to do with your result.

If you want a deep result but want to leave it to the next generation to sort out:

```
ByteCount[FullSimplify[PiecewiseExpand[phase // ToPiecewise]]] // Timing

(* to the next generation *)
```

If you want an impressive, publishable result but are ready to move onto new challenges

```
ByteCount[FullSimplify[PiecewiseExpand[phase // ToIf]]] // Timing

 (* {8.05217, 56584} *)
```

If you want a promising result but one that evidently needs more funding

```
 ByteCount[FullSimplify[PiecewiseExpand[phase // ToWhich]]] // Timing

 (* {18.3734, 73240} *)
```

If you want a promising result that but one that clearly needs a new research group to investigate further

```
ByteCount[PiecewiseExpand[phase // ToWhich, True, Reals, 
    Method -> {
      "ConditionSimplifier" -> Reduce, 
      "ValueSimplifier" -> Together}]] // Timing

(* {22.3115, 168328} *)
```

If you're desperate for a spectacular result in a Hail Mary for a Nobel

```
ByteCount[nobel = FullSimplify[PiecewiseExpand[phase // ToSwitch]]] // Timing
nobel

 (* 
   {0.008306, 200}
   -2 e + 2 e1
  *)
```

Comment: I was impressed by your answer! May I ask the subsequent question, explained in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/256765/manipulating-piecewise-function-with-many-cases-efficiently ? In this question, I want to perform a simple summation over the result that you find, but it takes a very long time...

Comment: @eigenvalue Well I hope you weren't too impressed! The intent was to show that one should be a little suspicious of such wildly different outcomes both in the time taken and the resulting simplifications. And especially here where the timing out of `ToPiecewise` is perhaps the way with the most precedence followed by `If`, `Which` and finally the rarely used `Switch` for this usage. Hence while `PiecewiseExpand` is a powerful tool I would be carefully prodding and checking the equivalence of all outputs. I'm afraid don't have much time currently but perhaps providing some extra context ...

Comment: ... might prod a wider response (e.g. what are equivalent outputs? which outputs make sense for your application? what is the motivation and why does it need to be `PiecewiseExpand`ed?)

Comment: As explained in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/256765/summing-piecewise-function-with-many-cases-efficiently , my motivation for this question related to numerically integrate a function. I have a integrand that is a product of some function and the `phase`. I expect that by using `PiecewiseExpand`, I can locate where the sum over `phase` is nonzero. This makes me to integrate only in the subregion, thereby simplifying the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the complete result quite fast, if you take into accout phase is a linear sum  phase == pp0 + e ppe + e1 ppe1 + e2 ppe2 with the ppi dependent on {d,t,t1,t2}.

First regard the coefficients separately and than combine them.

```
phase = 2 Sign[
  t] (1/2 (-1 + e) - 1/2 (1 + e) Sign[t]) + (1/2 (-1 + e1) + 
   1/2 (1 + e1) Sign[d - t1]) (-1 + Sign[t1]) - (1/2 (-e + e1) + 
   1/2 (e + e1) Sign[d + t - t1]) (-1 + 
   Sign[-t + t1]) - (1/2 (-1 + e2) + 
   1/2 (1 + e2) Sign[d - t2]) (-1 + Sign[t2]) + (1/2 (-e + e2) + 
   1/2 (e + e2) Sign[d + t - t2]) (-1 + Sign[-t + t2]) + 
2 (1/2 (-e1 + e2) + 1/2 (e1 + e2) Sign[t1 - t2]) Sign[-t1 + t2] //
Expand;

vars = DeleteCases[Variables[phase] /. Sign[aa_] -> aa, e | e1 | e2]

cond = Thread[vars != 0]

coe = Coefficient[phase, #] & /@ {e, e1, e2} // Simplify

coe0 = phase - {e, e1, e2}.coe // Simplify

(pp0 = PiecewiseExpand[coe0, cond, Reals] // 
Simplify[#, cond] &) // Timing

(ppe = PiecewiseExpand[coe[[1]], cond, Reals] // 
Simplify[#, cond] &) // Timing

(ppe1 = PiecewiseExpand[coe[[2]], cond, Reals] // 
Simplify[#, cond] &) // Timing

(ppe2 = PiecewiseExpand[coe[[3]], cond, Reals] // 
Simplify[#, cond] &) // Timing

(ppall = PiecewiseExpand[pp0 + e ppe + e1 ppe1 + e2 ppe2, cond, 
 Reals] // Simplify[#, cond] &) // Timing
```

[image]

Test it 1000 times

```
And @@ Table[ppall == phase /. 
Thread[{d, t, t1, t2} -> RandomReal[{-10, 10}, 4]] // 
Simplify, {1000}]

(*   True   *)
```